# Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to C# programming and worker role concept. I referred the documentation of worker role program, but I could not understand completely the difference of OnStart() and Run().

I want to move my Twitter console application to worker role program. If anyone have a reference program can you please share it?

Comment: There is quite a bit of documentation about Cloud Services (which covers web and worker roles). A simple search will tell you all about the lifecycle events in detail (and it goes beyond just `OnStart()` and `Run()`). References to a program (e.g. tutorial/offsite resource) are off-topic types of questions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OnStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx) method is where you would write your role's initialization code where as [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx) method is the main method of your role.

If you override `OnStart` method, you must ensure that it returns `true`. If it returns false, then your role will not start.

Your `Run` method should never terminate. If it terminates, then your role will be recycled.

You can read more about the methods here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.aspx.